# Spring Data Elasticsearch - Create keyword field with normalizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using the spring-data-elasticsearch project to interface with our elasticsearch clusters, and have been using it now for around a year. Recently, we moved to elasticsearch 5.x (from 2.x) where we now have the "keyword" datatype.

I would like to index these keywords as lowercase values, which I know can be done with field normalizers. I can't find anywhere in the documentation or online where I can add a normalizer to a field through the annotation based mapping. 
E.g

```
@Field(type = FieldType.keyword, <some_other_param = some_normalizer>)
```

Is this something that can be done? I know that we can use JSON based mapping definitions as well, so I will fall back to that option if needed, but would like to be able to do it this way if possible.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, for anyone looking at this, the answer is there is not a way to do this at this time.

You can do this, however, by creating your mappings file as JSON in the Elasticsearch format. See:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

You can then create that JSON file and link it to your Domain model with.

`@Mapping(mappingPath = "some/path/mapping.json")`

Note that this is not, in my experience, compatible with the provided annotation based mapping for fields.

Answer (score 5):

Since the pull request of @xhaggi has been merged (spring-data-elasticsearch 3.1.3+ or Spring Boot 2.1.1), we have a `normalizer` field in the `@Field` annotation.

To use it, we need:

1. declare a `@Field` or an `@InnerField` with params `type = FieldType.Keyword, normalizer = "%NORMALIZER_NAME%"`
2. add `@Setting(settingPath = "%PATH_TO_NORMALIZER_JSON_FILE%")` at the class level.
3. put the normalizer mapping into a json file at `%PATH_TO_NORMALIZER_JSON_FILE%`

[Example of usage](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/222/commits/2632fa250b78c55a62995c7d0c6939b19bd1ee13#diff-59a5be66a8efdf3e8f65bd53dcc45609)

Answer (score 1):

There is a pending issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-492 waiting for review.